# Unable to establish connection using jms jndi

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms, websphere-liberty

I am very new to JMS & JNDI, and I'm trying to receive message from a queue programatically, but I am not sure how I can connect to the server. I have Websphere console UI where I login to manage all my queues. This console UI is hosted at `linux-server:7276`. Below is the UI link

```
https://my-server:9043/ibm/console
```

I have referred to the sample classes from IBM MQ `JmsJndiConsumer`:

```java
String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
String initialContextUrl = "ldap://my-server:9043"
Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, initialContextUrl);
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);     
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(environment);
```

It always throws an error in the context `Connection or outbound has closed`.

The queue I am trying to connect to has these details:

```
Connection factories : jms/atConnectionFactory
queue-manager : appit-node.Sit-TBus
Bus name : TBus
queue name : jms/appitone-event
Bootstrap Member : linux-server:7276
```

Comment: Does your ldap contain JNDI settings?   In most cases I've seen people just use the file representation on JNDI that is generated as a file called `.bindings`.   This would contain the host name and listener port of the queue manager you want to connect to along with the MQ channel name and possibly other details such as a cipher suite and cert label.   Many apps just specify these details directly in code on the connection factory object.   You don't really provide enough info to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `my-server:9043` for **both** your HTTPS and LDAP server. Both of these can't be using the same port on the same machine so one of them must be wrong which is almost certainly why it's failing.